# SharePoint Framework (SPFx) access custom API secured with AzureAD

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, spfx

We have developed a little SharePoint Framework WebPart (SPFx). The WebPart should get his data from our custom api on our own server. The api is secured with AzureAD. We already tried this: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-api-secured-with-aad
and this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient
but unfortunately, none of this worked for us. 
What we already did: 
-   Our custom api was registered in our AzureAD under App Registrations in Azure.
-   In Office 365 SharePoint we approved the API in the SharePoint Admin Section.

Must the api also be hosted in Azure or is it ok if it is on our own server? We receive the warning:
Access to fetch at  from origin 'https://sharepoint.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: You can host it on your own server however, if an HTTP request is Cross origin then the browser restrict cross-origin requests unless the response includes the right CORs headers. Please refer to this SharePoint forum thread-https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/254050/spfx-calls-blocked-by-cors-policy if this helps to resolve your issue.  Also, take a look at http://eugeneagafonov.com/post/38312919044/iis-options-cors-aspnet-webapi-en

Comment: Did you configure on you API and on Azure the cors configuration? (Azure App Service on the left menu API > Cors)